# Multi-threading issue with Python data processing pipeline

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm working on a data-intensive project that involves processing large datasets through a custom pipeline. The pipeline consists of multiple stages, each handling a specific aspect of data transformation. To improve performance, I decided to parallelize these stages using the `concurrent.futures` module for multi-threading.

Here is an over simplification of the current code:

```py
import concurrent.futures

class DataProcessor:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def stage_one(self, chunk):
        result = [item * 2 for item in chunk]
        return result

    def stage_two(self, chunk):
        result = [item + 5 for item in chunk]
        return result

    def run_pipeline(self):
        chunk_size = len(self.data) // 2
        chunk_one, chunk_two = self.data[:chunk_size], self.data[chunk_size:]

        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
            future_one = executor.submit(self.stage_one, chunk_one)
            future_two = executor.submit(self.stage_two, chunk_two)

            concurrent.futures.wait([future_one, future_two])

            result_one = future_one.result()
            result_two = future_two.result()

        final_result = result_one + result_two

        return final_result

def load_large_dataset():
    return list(range(1000000))

data = load_large_dataset()
processor = DataProcessor(data)
result = processor.run_pipeline()

print(result[:10])
```

When running the pipeline I'm encountering some peculiar behavior, no matter how large the input is I seem to be getting minimal to no performance improvement, compared to a single thread execution.

I've tried resorting to different threading strategies, such as using the `threading` module directly, but the issue seemed to remain.

Any insights, examples or resources would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You would see much larger boost in performance if you used ProcessPoolExecutor

Comment: I'm getting the same result every time I run your code.  And you won't be getting any speed up using multithreading because of the Global Python Lock.  You'd really need multiprocessing.

Comment: FWIW: I don't see any "pipeline" in your example. I only see one thread that performs one operation on one half of the data, and another thread that does something different to the other half. In a pipeline, _all_ of the data would be subject to the same _sequence_ of operations.

Comment: @FrankYellin Wow, had never heard of the Global Lock before. Just read a little about it now, interesting stuff, I'm probably gonna change my design philosophy now. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @SolomonSlow Did not know a pipeline referred to such a specific setup, I'll do a better use of the word from now on, thanks!

Comment: To be more specific, "pipeline" means that the output from the each "stage" becomes the input to the next stage. I worked on one commercial product in which each stage of a pipeline had its own input queue and one or more dedicated threads. Each thread picked tasks from its input queue, performed the tasks, and placed the results into the input queue of the next stage. But, there could be other "pipeline" architectures in which the coupling between threads and pipeline stages is not so strict.